# xelatex error: Undefined control sequence

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors

When I'm compiling the following code with `xelatex`, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \luatex_if_engine:T
```

file: `fontspec-xetex.sty`

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=12]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
  Hallo
\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably need to update your expl3 packages using  your texlive or miktex package manager

Comment: Any news here? Btw: You should not use xelatex and babel (have a look at polyglossia).